# bootstrap 3 active class always return to home

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

i want to add active class dynamically to menu list items but the code works but for a second and the class active never stay on .
here is my code :

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $("ul.nav li").click(function(e) {
    $("ul.nav li.active").removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass("active");
});
```

HTML:

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbarHeaderCollapse">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li class="active"><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Update info<b class="caret"></b></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                 <li><a href="changepassword.php">Change password</a></li>
                 <li><a href="update.php">update name</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="logout.php">logout</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: so, in your structure, at what point are you adding the active class? is it when they click on the menu `li`?

Comment: I agree with @Octav, according to your code, everytime you click the link, your li does in fact change, but each link will direct you to another page where all script is then "refreshed", thus losing whatever prior actions

Comment: are you using PHP as your backend language?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with the use of localstorage-

**Storing a persistent item on click-**

```
$('.nav li').click(function () {
    $(this).addClass('active');

    //Here you set the item in storage                    
    localStorage.setItem("LastActiveMenu", $(this).index());    

});
```

**Get the last active item on document ready-**

```
var lastActiveMenuItem = localStorage.getItem("LastActiveMenu");
if (lastActiveMenuItem != null) {
    var menuItem = $('.nav').find('li').eq(lastActiveMenuItem);
    menuItem.addClass('active');
}
```

Answer (score -2):

When you are redirected to the next page, the DOM reloads and looses the setting. You should do it in back-end not in front-end.

If you're using PHP, the code should be something like this:

```
$thisPage = "contact";
<a href="/contact" <?php if ( $thisPage == "contact" ) { echo "class='active'" } ?>>Contact Us</a>
```

Comment: you mean i should add the class in a php script ??

Comment: @JordiCastilla well... it's much more helpful than your contribution to this question. Wait ... what contribution?

Comment: @Octav This is not giving any help to answer the question, only to guide the OP, so it must be a comment, not an aswer... So in order to improve yours and others experience in SO please, [read this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17447/answer-or-comment-whats-the-etiquette) and [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/118582/what-is-an-acceptable-answer)

Comment: @JordiCastilla According to http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/118582/what-is-an-acceptable-answer point no.8, my answer is a valid one and you're too zealous in "guiding the OP" which makes it a bad experience for users.

Comment: also,... I'm not guiding the OP, i'm trying to guide you, OP has his answer a long time ago, but no thanks to you! did you realized? ;)

Comment: @JordiCastilla My answer offers a different way of solving the problem. If you don't understand it then it's your problem. I can see it was understood by others. Caps an bold text won't make your point valid so maybe you should read some guidelines on how to efficiently and politely communicate your opinions. Try www.netmanners.com.